# Can't remove Chromium from Software Store

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, google-chrome, chromium

I installed Chromium from Software app, but I decided to with chrome-stable. Clicking remove in software app says 'Removing...' then it cancels it and doesn't remove it.

Via terminal this doesn't work either

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chromium-browser-l10n : Depends: chromium-browser (>= 58.0.3029.96-0ubuntu0.17.04.1352) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: chromium-browser (< 58.0.3029.96-0ubuntu0.17.04.1352.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Comment: It says "You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these." so what happened after you did that?

Comment: @Rinzwind oh well, I'm stupid, sorry it's my first day on linux

Comment: please specify what ubuntu version you're using for future users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running doing this:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will repair all the broken/corrupt install packages, and in this case, including the chromium-browser. After this has completed, try uninstalling via the software center or via **`sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser`** and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I did `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and then tried to remove it and it worked.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh if it worked for him than it is a solution. plus I really don't see how it "doesn't provide an answer to the question"

Comment: @tatsu removed the review comment, but it seems like a duplicate if that solution worked

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh of what post?

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
sudo snap remove chromium
```

and it worked, can't recall if I installed it through snap though but it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the things with fix broken installations - but nothing helps
chromium still shown as install in the Ubuntu Software and I couldn't remove it.

Finally I got remember that it wasn't install through apt but with snap, so I did

```
sudo snap remove chromium
```

and oooppp it is removed.