# Not able to remove chromium from ubuntu 18.04 - error: snap "chromium" has "remove-snap" change in progress

Tags: software-center, uninstall, chromium

I tried to uninstall chromium from "Ubuntu software" application . I was not able to do it and thus i followed steps given on [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915299/cant-remove-chromium-from-software-store)  . However after that i am neither able to uninstall it or open it .

Error messages i am getting :

1.While removing from software center : it's just not removing .

2.While using command line :

```
$ sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'chromium-browser' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm9
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
```

3. when using another command :

```
$sudo snap remove chromium
error: snap "chromium" has "remove-snap" change in progress
```

After point 3 , I aborted the snap process of chromium using sudo snap abort but still it's giving same message .

Now i am able to open it but i want to uninstall it.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1329922/edit) your question, and post the error message which you get when you run the command(s). You can put the terminal output between three ``` so that it will be rendered as code, like ```code```

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi done

Answer (score 0):

Software center is connected to `apt`. The second option you tried says `Package 'chromium-browser' is not installed, so not removed` meaning apt did not install it therefore software center naturally can not do anything to it. The third command suggests you used snap to install chromium. You can use snap store to remove chromium with a gui or from a cli. You appear to be stuck in between and can use the following commands.

```
snap changes
# Copy the ID
sudo snap abort <ID>
sudo snap remove chromium
```

[Source](https://www.fosslicious.com/2019/12/fix-snap-error-change-in-progress.html)

Comment: I did snap changes , then snap abort <ID> . But after that it's still not able to remove it and saying error: snap "chromium" has "remove-snap" change in progress . In snap changes it's still showing : 213  Error   today at 00:17 IST      today at 00:58 IST even after aborting it.

Comment: @laser does restarting the computer help?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I tried restarting and it didn't work .

Comment: @laser did you do `sudo snap abort` or just `snap abort`?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi restart should not work because these days people do smart logging of operations so that if something unexpectedly shuts down, damage can be minimized. I'm guessing a checkpoint already exists, even if you (force) shutdown, upon restarting you will return to the checkpoint.

Comment: @Mr.rk i tried with both

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you further since I am not able to replicate the issue on my computer. There seems to be two options, either the process needs to be terminated (which I proposed in my answer) or you need to allow the process to complete. Since neither of this is happening, I think you best bet is to contact the developers of snap. Good luck!

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Cannot remove because "error: snap "chromium" has "remove-snap" change in progress", but I have confirmed it is not in progress because I aborted it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try these steps in that order**

```
sudo snap revert  <package name>
sudo snap refresh <package name>
sudo snap remove  <package name>
```

Those steps seemed to work for me very well.